# LLVM: declaring an indirect function call in C that becomes a storedinst?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing some LLVM code to look for indirect calls. For now I've created C code that triggers llvm::loadinstructions, llvm::bitcast instruction, etc

However, I'm unable to write any indirect C code that triggers this:

```
if(CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&*S)) {
  if(!CI->getCalledFunction()) {
    if(StoreInst *SI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(CI->getCalledValue())) 
      /* do something */
}}}
```

Comment: I would guess you need something that works with function pointers? We seem to have C++ code with polymorphism that results in indirect calls in LLVM.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your condition includes reading from `StoreInst`?
If you create the following function, you will reach your condition but with `LoadInst`.

```
extern int printf(const char *fmt, ...);

static void foo() {
  printf("Hello!\n");
}

int main() {
  void (*pointer)(void) = foo;

  pointer();

  return 0;
}
```

Corresponding LLVM IR:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 !dbg !7 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca void ()*, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata void ()** %2, metadata !11, metadata !15), !dbg !16
  store void ()* @foo, void ()** %2, align 8, !dbg !16
  %3 = load void ()*, void ()** %2, align 8, !dbg !17
  call void %3(), !dbg !17
  ret i32 0, !dbg !18
}
```

Compile this with `clang -g -c -emit-llvm main.c`.

The following code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  LLVMContext context;
  const char *path = "main.bc";
  auto BufferOrError = MemoryBuffer::getFile(path);
  if (!BufferOrError) {
    std::cout << "Can't open bitcode file '" << path << "'\n";
    return 1;
  }

  auto moduleOrError = parseBitcodeFile(BufferOrError->get()->getMemBufferRef(), context);
  if (!moduleOrError) {
    std::cout << "Can't parse bitcode file '" << path << "'\n";
    return 1;
  }

  Module *module = moduleOrError->get();

  for (auto &F: *module) {
    for (auto &BB: F) {
      for (auto &I: BB) {
        if (CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I)) {
          if (!CI->getCalledFunction()) {
            CI->dump();

            if (StoreInst *SI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(CI->getCalledValue())) {
              errs() << "StoreInst\n";
              CI->dump();
            }

            if (LoadInst *LI = dyn_cast<LoadInst>(CI->getCalledValue())) {
              errs() << "LoadInst\n";
              LI->dump();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
call void %3(), !dbg !17
LoadInst
%3 = load void ()*, void ()** %2, align 8, !dbg !17
```

Comment: you are correct, I am able to trigger loadinstr but not storeinst. I'm not sure if my code will trigger a storedinst, will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: Try asking on [llvm-dev mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/llvm-dev). It is very likely that you will get the answer there.